# GCM to a group of users

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

This is my case:

I have a database with 10k ID client to notify, most of these are not valid, I just have 4 valids ID Client to notify by push notification.

Why I am doing that?

I want to be sure I can handle that size of IDs.

How I am notify them?

Well, I am using  this format:

```
https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=AIzaSyZ-1u...0GBYzPu7Udno5aA

{ "data": {
    "score": "5x1",
    "time": "15:10"
  },
  "to" : "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1..."
}
```

So I have to add all the keys, when I am attaching all the keys (10k) I am having troubles I think gcm will not allow me to send that size of ids.

So I want to know from your perspective which is the best way to notify a hudge group of users.

I have been thinking in handling the keys in a kind of chunks for example with 200 keys each push notification.

I have been reviewing in push GCM with a group but I don't have clear this. I have seen the documentation:

https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/notifications

And there is a part:

```
The maximum number of members allowed for a notification_key is 20.
```

It means I have to create a group but I just will be able to notify 20 user maximun?

There is a way to create a group and put on it 10k (or more) users and just send message to a group? and then GCM service will notify all them.

Comment: Can you send x time the same message ?

Comment: Do you mean? 1 by 1? sending 10k request to GCM service?

Comment: 20 by 20 look like google dont allow more.

Comment: I believe that what you have created is [Device Group Messaging](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/notifications) which only allows 20 devices. You want to try [Topic Messaging](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/topic-messaging) which can accomodate a lot more. You just have to register those devices to a topic that you have created. In this case, you may want to create one then register those 10k devices to that topic.

Comment: Thanks @gerardnimo without a dude I will research about ! I am new in this. I think that's what I need, I will let you know

Comment: @gerardnimo I have been reading about, do you know how can you achieve it in cordova? It seems I need the Instance ID of the app in my device: https://developers.google.com/instance-id/guides/android-implementation  I don't know how to get even researching in internet